# Installation of UBUNTU

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying the option of "try-ubuntu-before-you-install"

I've burned the ISO file onto a CD, told the laptop to boot from CD first, but it ignores the CD and boots the old XP from the HDD.

Any ideas?

Comment: Checked [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)?

Comment: Does your CD/DVD drive work otherwise? (If you burned the CD on that drive, the answer would be yes...)

Answer (score 0):

may be your cd is not corretly burned, try it on another pc to be sure or directly try to burn another one or create an bootable usb key instead, you have a tool for that under windows usbuntu.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can download again from Ubuntu website and record onto a CD (or DVD) using an ISO recording program, such as DaemonTools, PowerISO or NERO.

Ubuntu 12.04 Download: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Other Ubuntu Versions: http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out your CD from inside windows. Do you see a bunch of files and directories, or do you see Ubunutu-something.iso  ? If the ISO file is on the disk rather than the contents of the iso you have to burn another CD. You want to use the "burn image" option on your CD burner. Check out link:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto